# Error in my project: [undefined] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create an app but it is facing some issues. When I run the command `npm start` it started showing this error.

I'm trying to upgrade the `react-router-dom` from v5 to v6 but I am getting this error message.

> Error: [undefined] is not a `<Route>` component. All component
> children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Landing from './pages/Landing/Landing'
import ResumeCreate from './pages/ResumeCreate/ResumeCreate'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
          <Route path="/create" exact>
            <ResumeCreate />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router> 
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Resumecreate.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import constants from '../../config/constants';
import FocusTrap from "../../helpers/app.helper";
import routes from '../../routes';
import "../../styles/App.css"
import "../../styles/darkmode.css"

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const { ROUTES } = constants;
const { Home } = routes;

function ResumeCreate({
  editorOpen,
  toolbarOpen,
  moreVisibilityOpen,
  darkMode,
  autoSave,
}) {
  const [autoSaveToastId, setToastId] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!autoSave) {
      const id = toast.warn(
        'To prevent data loss, download your resume using the Download button or turn on auto save!',
        {
          autoClose: false,
          position: 'bottom-right',
          closeOnClick: false,
        },
      );
      setToastId(id);
    } else {
      toast.dismiss(autoSaveToastId);
      setToastId('');
    }
  }, [autoSave]);

  return (
    <div className={classNames('App', { darkMode })}>
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-center"
        autoClose={3000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        closeButton={false}
        rtl={false}
      />
      <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME.PATH} element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <FocusTrap full={editorOpen} mobile={toolbarOpen || moreVisibilityOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ResumeCreate);
```

Is it problem with the version?

Errors:-

```
components.tsx:409  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
at Router (components.tsx:409:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

> Blockquote

Comment: I don't know what the error's from, but it's not a good sign you have 2 BrowserRouter's. You should only have one BrowserRouter, close to your root

Comment: Should I delete BroswerRoute from this code?ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);

Answer (score 0):

edit your index

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <Router  >
     <App />
  </Router>
);
```

file code

Comment: Now it is showing this error
react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createRoot is not a function
TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createRoot is not a function

Comment: package.json 
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",

Comment: update react to ^18.2.0

Comment: AGAIN ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Answer (score 0):

There should also be only 1 router per React app. Remove the extraneous routers from `App` and `ResumeCreate` since the entire app is already wrapped in a `BrowserRouter`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`ResumeCreate` is not a `Route` component, render it on a `Route`'s `element` prop, not as a child component, and ensure a wildcard splat `"*"` matcher is appended to it's route so the descendent routes that `ResumeCreate` is rendering can also be matched and rendered.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path="/create/*" element={<ResumeCreate />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
...
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function ResumeCreate({
  editorOpen,
  toolbarOpen,
  moreVisibilityOpen,
  darkMode,
  autoSave,
}) {
  ....

  return (
    <div className={classNames('App', { darkMode })}>
      <ToastContainer
        ....
      />

      <Routes>
        <Route path={ROUTES.HOME.PATH} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>

      <FocusTrap full={editorOpen} mobile={toolbarOpen || moreVisibilityOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ERROR   react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createRoot is not a function
TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createRoot is not a function-

Comment: @anushkarastogi I noticed in your comment under another answer that you still have `react-router@5` as a project dependency. I suspect this is the issue. You should remove `react-router` as a dependency and have only the `react-router-dom@6` dependency.

Comment: AGAIN ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Comment: @anushkarastogi But it is a *different* error now. What in the code is trying to read a `pathname` property? Can you edit the post to include the complete error message and error stacktrace?